# Making a linked list and the problem is it keeps saying the pointer type is incompatible

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct _stdata{
    int stid;
    int sttype;
    struct stdata *nextptr;
};

typedef struct _stdata stdata;
stdata *new = malloc(sizeof(stdata));
new->nextptr = new;
```

Comment: did not mean to put list in there, it is suppose to be new

Comment: Your `nextptr` member points to a `struct stdata`, not a `struct _stdata`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `new` as a variable name, since it's a keyword in C++.  Though it won't cause errors as long as you compile the code as C rather than C++, it seems like something that could easily come back to bite you later, and would be easy to avoid now.

Comment: it was type defined as stdata not _stdata.  And these arent the exact names im using in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your struct your should have

```
struct _stdata *nextptr;
```

Comment: Well that works, but I don't know why my other codes work then.  But thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's how your definition is set up. The following should work for you:

```
typedef struct stdata stdata;
struct stdata
{
    int stid;
    int sttype;
    stdata *nextptr;
};
```

Alternatively, you can do [what Doug suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768442/making-a-linked-list-and-the-problem-is-it-keeps-saying-the-pointer-type-is-incom/5768461#5768461), but typedefing your struct like this makes your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error/warning on this line?

```
stdata *new = malloc(sizeof(stdata));
```

You just need to include a cast:

```
stdata *new = (stdata*) malloc(sizeof(stdata));
```

By the way "new" is a *terrible* variable name, as it's a reserved word in C++ and it looks *very* confusing to most people!

Comment: Nope. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code but to get it to compile, you must change the pointer type in the struct to stdata, struct _stdata is causing you problems.  Also place the typedef at the top of file, and include stdlib.h for malloc.

Answer (score 0):

in your struct you've used stdata before defining it. you should use _stdata instead